# Debian: SSH: "PermitRootLogin=forced-commands-only" stopped working

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

I have several servers running Debian Lenny.

Just recently I discovered the **PermitRootLogin=forced-commands-only** directive for ssh, which allows me to run a scripted rsync as root with an ssl key, without enabling more generalized root ssh access.

However, last week this stopped working - it appears on all of my servers -  and I can't figure out why.

Everything continues to work fine with **PermitRootLogin=yes**, but I would prefer to block root logins - especially via passwords.

The day it stopped working, we reconfigured some of the ports on one of our switches (which we later reverted), but I can't see that affecting this, since it still works with PermitRootLogin set to yes.

**How can I diagnose why the forced-commands-only directive has apparently stopped working?**

Comment: How about looking in the logs on the server to see what it says when you try?  Up the logging in sshd?

Comment: I tried running sshd with the -d (debug) switch, which gave alot of output, but was very cryptic to me.  It appeared that it was accepting the certificate, and then dropping the connection immediately afterward with no further explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only" requires that all connections, via SSH as root, need to use public key authentication and that a command be associated with that key (like 'validate-rsync').

If you want to login as root but only with keys use:

```
PermitRootLogin = without-password
```

To restrict rsync to a defined ssh-key you can specify in your authorized_keys:

```
from="<ip>",command="/usr/local/sbin/validate-rsync" ssh-dss AAAAZ5Hbl......
```

And save this wrapper to: /usr/local/sbin/validate-rsync

```
#!/bin/sh 

case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in 
*\&*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
*\(*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
*\{*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
*\;*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
*\<*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
*\`*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
*\|*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
rsync\ --server*) 
$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND 
;; 
*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
esac
```

There is a slightly more complicated script shipped with rsync to do the same,
http://www.samba.org/ftp/unpacked/rsync/support/rrsync

Answer (score 0):

If rsync can login as root, then anybody can: there's no difference for the server what's knocking at.
I believe it was either experimental/hacky, or they just realized it's not more secure than 'yes'.

I'd suggest you disabling password auth for root (e.g. remove the password at all and use `sudo` when needed) and rely on key auth method.

Comment: Are you saying that openssh has disabled this option recently?  If so, how can I confirm that?

Comment: I'm not sure, just guessing :) anyway, it's not more secure than just `yes`!